# Universal morphism as an edge case of a universal cone

Tags: category-theory

If I understand correctly, a terminal morphism $(c, \phi)$, is just an edge case of a limit.

So if $(N, \psi: N \to D)$, with the apex $N$, and the base $D$, is a limit, and if $\psi$ is a family of morphisms containing a single morphism $\phi$, and if $c = N$, then their definitions should be equivalent. Is this correct?

And if so, is saying "*cone $x$ fulfills the terminal property*" a valid statement?

Comment: One can view (co)limits as terminal objects in certain "auxiliary" categories -- is this what you mean? (Thus a terminal object is just a (co)limit of an empty diagram)

Comment: What do you mean by "$(N,\psi)$ is a limit"? What is $N$ and what is $\psi$ generically? I assume it is some representation of a diagram or a limiting cone or something.

Comment: @DerekElkins $\psi$ is a family of arrows from an object $N$ to $D$, the diagram. That makes N the apex of the cone, and D the base.

Comment: Add it to the question. You should also use a notation that doesn't completely suppress the diagram $D$. You could say something like "If $(N,\psi)$ is a limiting cone over diagram $D$ with apex $N$..." As to the question itself, what is the diagram $D$ in this case? What does that imply about $\psi$?

Comment: @MCT No, I'm talking more about the (co)limit of the category $\mathbf{1}$ with one object and one morphism. Saying $psi$ is the cone to $D*$ is equal as saying $\psi$ is a universal morphism.

Comment: If you are talking about terminal objects, that occurs when the diagram $D$ is *empty*, so there can be *no* arrows in $\psi$.